# Prove or disprove transcendence of numbers

Tags: number-theory, transcendental-numbers

I have two in one question:

1) Let $\{p_n\}_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$ be sequence of all prime numbers. Is number $\displaystyle\alpha = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} 10^{-p_n}$  transcendental number?

2) Let $\{F_n\}_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ be Fibonacci sequence with initial values $F_1=1$ and $F_2=2$. Is number $\displaystyle\beta = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} 10^{-F_n}$  transcendental number?

If anyone thinks of something better to retag it with, be my guest.

Comment: Usually people here prefer if you ask one question per post, to avoid this annoying situation in which someone can answer one of the questions and not the other.

Comment: For the first question see [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/42697/) and [this MathOverflow question](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/114905/). The question seems to be open.

Comment: @MJD Sorry for that.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your second number has been proved transcendental. A somewhat more general result about numbers of the form $\sum 10^{-\lfloor \beta^k\rfloor}$ is mentioned in the [Wikipedia list](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transcendental_number#Numbers_proved_to_be_transcendental) of numbers that have been proved transcendental.

**Added:** It has been pointed out that the Wikipedia reference is, to put it mildly, thin. To chase down information about Sturmian sequences, one can for example look at [this article](http://combinatorics.cis.strath.ac.uk/download/RiZa.pdf) and its references. I believe that the original result is due to Mahler.

Comment: is that it? mentioned with no citation on wikipedia?