# A binary irrational with bits defined by primes

Tags: prime-numbers, irrational-numbers, transcendental-numbers

Define a number $q$ in binary notation whose $n$-th bit is
$1$ for $n$ prime, and $0$ for $n$ composite.
So its 2nd, 3rd, 5th, 7th, 11th, etc. bits are $1$,
with all other bits $0$. Here is $q$ out
to its $101$-st bit:
$$.01101010001010001010001000001
   010000010001010001000001000
   001010000010001010000010001
   000001000000010001$$
What is known about $q$? ($\approx 0.414683_{10}$). Has it been investigated? Does it have a name?
It is irrational. But is it transcendental?

Comment: It breaks tables. I have a marvelous proof of this fact, but it is too large to contain in the body of your question.

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/42697/what-is-the-name-of-this-number-is-it-transcendental

Comment: See also the answer linked in Dan's reference: [Are these numbers irrational and/or transcendental?](http://mathoverflow.net/a/114910/6094).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your number is known as the *prime constant*. If we denote it by $\rho$, we have:

$$
\rho =\sum _{{p\in\mathbb{P}}}{\frac  {1}{2^{p}}}=\sum _{{n=1}}^{\infty }{\frac  {\chi _{{{\mathbb  {P}}}}(n)}{2^{n}}},
$$

where $\mathbb{P}$ denotes the set of prime numbers and $\chi _{{{\mathbb  {P}}}}$ is the characteristic function of prime numbers, i.e., the function such that for positive integer $n$:

$$
{\displaystyle \chi_\mathbb{P}(n):={\begin{cases}1&{\text{if }}n\in \mathbb{P},\\0&{\text{if }}n\notin \mathbb{P}.\end{cases}}}
$$

The decimal expansion of $\rho$ begins with:
\begin{align}
\rho&=0.414682509851111660248109622\ldots \\
&=0.011010100010100010_2.
\end{align}

and is included in the OEIS as sequence [A051006](https://oeis.org/A051006).