# Number of elements of $3n$ binary tuples, where the ordinates add up to $2n$.

Tags: combinatorics

I have the following problem.

Take  $\Omega_n=\{(a_1, a_2 , \cdots , a_{3n})|  a_i= 0\rm{\,or}\, 1\}$. Define
$A_n=\{\omega \in \Omega_n|\exists k, \sum _{i=1}^{3k} a_i = 2k\}$ and
$ S_m=\{(a_1, a_2 , \cdots , a_{3m}) \in A_m|\inf \{ k,| \sum _{i=1}^{3k} a_i = 2k\}=m\}  $
we are interested in finding
$|S_m|$ the cardinality of $S_m$

There is a straightforward recursive formula$S_n={3n \choose 2n}-\left (S_1 {3(n-1) \choose 2(n-1)}+S_2{3(n-2) \choose 2(n-2)}+ \cdots S_{n-1} {3\cdot(1) \choose 2\cdot(1)} \right )=  {3n\choose 2n}-\left (\sum _{i=1}^{n-1}S_i {3(n-i)\choose 2(n-i)} \right )$ I was not sure how to compute that so I used [OEIS](http://oeis.org/search?q=3,6,21,90,429&sort=&language=english&go=Search) to see if it has some nice formula. After finding by hand the first values $ 3,6,21,90,429   $ it suggested me the formula $ \frac{2}{3n-1}{3n\choose 2n}$. I managed to prove it by induction.

I would be interested in some combinatorial proof of that, a bijection would be highly appreciated.

Comment: What is "inf" ?  Do you mean the smallest $k$ for which the summation holds?

Comment: @Doc out of habit infimum, yes exactly

Comment: Not at all there yet, but it seems interesting that the answer also takes the form $\frac{1}{n} {3n-1\choose n}$.

Comment: oops .... that should say $\frac{3}{3n-1} {3n-1\choose n}$.

Comment: @Doc: Or $\frac3n\binom{3n-2}{n-1}$, though that isn’t obviously any more useful.

Comment: I had also given some thought to ${3n} {3n\choose 2n} {{3n\choose 2}^{-1}}$.  Nothing yet.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Code heads as 1 and tails as 0, and the problem can be phrased in the following way: Flip a fair coin until you have exactly twice as many heads as tails, and then stop.  The value of $|S_n|$ is the number of such sequences of coin flips that have length exactly $3n$.

For this rephrased version, I asked the same question as the OP a couple of years ago on this site, under "[Combinatorial proof of $\binom{3n}{n} \frac{2}{3n-1}$ as the answer to a coin-flipping problem](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/60991/2370)."  It took me a few weeks before I found an answer to my own question, so I wouldn't call this an easy combinatorial proof to come up with.  (In fact, I generalized my argument, recast it in terms of counting certain lattice paths, and got the argument published in the *Electronic Journal of Combinatorics* as "[Enumerating Lattice Paths Touching or Crossing the Diagonal at a Given Number of Lattice Points](http://www.combinatorics.org/ojs/index.php/eljc/article/view/v19i3p24/pdf).")

---

Anyway, I'll reproduce [my original combinatorial argument](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/66146/2370) here.  It uses the equivalent $|S_n| = \frac{3}{3n-1} \binom{3n-1}{n}$ as the formula to be proved.  It also uses the following result (see, for example, Section 7.5 of *Concrete Mathematics*):

**Raney's Lemma**: Let $a_1, ... a_m$ be a sequence of integers such that $\sum a_i = 1$. There is a unique index $j$ such that the partial sums of the sequence $a_j, a_{j+1}, ... a_{j+m-1}$ (cyclic indices) are positive.

On to the proof.

**Intro.**

Consider the sequences with $2n$ occurrences of $-1$ (i.e., $2n$ heads) and $n$ occurrences of $+2$ (i.e., $n$ tails).  We want to show that the number of these sequences with all partial sums nonzero is $\binom{3n-1}{n} \frac{3}{3n-1}$.  The complete sum and empty sum are clearly $0$, so "partial sum" excludes those two cases.  The sequences we want to count can be split into three groups: (1) all partial sums positive, (2) all partial sums negative, (3) some partial sums positive and some negative.

**Group 1: The number of these sequences with all partial sums positive is $\binom{3n-1}{n} \frac{1}{3n-1}$.**

This is the part that uses Raney's lemma.  If all partial sums are positive, the last element in the sequence must be $-1$.  Thus we want to count the number of sequences with $2n-1$ occurrences of $-1$ and $n$ occurrences of $+2$ that add to $+1$ and have all partial sums positive.  Ignoring the partial sums restriction, there are $\binom{3n-1}{n}$ such sequences.  If we partition these $\binom{3n-1}{n}$ sequences into equivalence classes based on cyclic shifts, Raney's lemma says that exactly one sequence in each equivalence class has all partial sums positive.  Because there are $3n-1$ elements in each sequence there are $3n-1$ sequences with the same set of cyclic shifts, and so there are $3n-1$ sequences in each equivalence class.  Thus the number of sequences in Group 1 is $\binom{3n-1}{n} \frac{1}{3n-1}$.

**Group 2: The number of these sequences with all partial sums negative is also $\binom{3n-1}{n} \frac{1}{3n-1}$.**

To see this, just reverse the sequences counted in Part 1.

**Group 3: The number of these sequences with some positive partial sums and some negative partial sums is, yet again, $\binom{3n-1}{n} \frac{1}{3n-1}$.**

This one is a little trickier.  First, because of the $-1$'s, it is not possible to switch from positive partial sums to negative partial sums.  Thus any sequence counted here must have exactly one switch: from negative partial sums to positive partial sums.  The switch must occur at some point where the partial sum is $-1$ and the next element is $+2$.  Thus we have some sequence $(a_1, \ldots, a_m, +2, a_{m+2}, \ldots, a_n)$ where the sums $a_1, a_1 + a_2, \ldots, a_1 + \cdots + a_m$ are all negative.  Consider the sequence $(+2, a_m, \ldots, a_2, a_1, a_{m+2}, \ldots, a_n)$.  Since $+2 + a_m + \cdots + a_1 = 1$, and $a_k + a_{k-1} + \cdots + a_1 < 0$ for all $k$, $1 \leq k \leq m$, it must be the case that $+2 + a_m + \cdots + a_{k+1} > 1$ for all $k$, $1 \leq k \leq m-1$.  So the sequence $(+2, a_m, \ldots, a_2, a_1, a_{m+2}, \ldots, a_n)$ is in Group 1.  To see that this mapping is a bijection, note that any sequence in Group 1 must start with $+2$ and have a first time that a partial sum is equal to $+1$.  Thus this transformation is reversible.

**Summing up.**

Putting Groups 1, 2, and 3 together we see that the total number of sequences we want to count is $\binom{3n-1}{n} \frac{3}{3n-1}$.

Comment: This is great! I didnt know about Ranney's Lemma, it was hidden all along this problem, it was nicely exploited!